# typesafe extraction of a given set of fields from an object

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, mapped-types

I get a json response (which becomes a object later on) from an API call which I can dynamically restrict to certain fields with queryparams.

I have typed the complete response already.

Now what I want to achive is to create a type which takes my given fields and returns an object-type, which only contains the given properties.

I am aware that there are utility types like Pick, but they do not work with nested objects.

example:

```js
interface ResponseInterface {
    a: {
        a: {
            a: number;
            b: string;
        };
        b: {
            a: string;
            b: boolean;
        };
    };
    b: {
        a: object | null;
        b: string;
    }[];
}


const filters = ['a.a.a', 'a.b.b', 'b.a']; //nested properties seperated by dots
const fakeFullResponse: ResponseInterface = { //calling the api without any filters
            a: {
                a: {
                    a: 123,
                    b: 'aab',
                },
                b: {
                    a: 'aba',
                    b: true,
                },
            },
            b: [
                {
                    a: null,
                    b: 'array bb',
                },
                {
                    a: {},
                    b: 'array bb',
                },
            ],
        };


interface ExpectedType { //after applying those filters to the object
    a: {
        a: {
            a: number;
        };
        b: {
            b: boolean;
        };
    };
    b: {
        a: null | object
    }[];
}

const fakeFilteredResponse: ExpectedType = { //calling the api with those fields above would get me this
            a: {
                a: {
                    a: 123,
                },
                b: {
                    b: true,
                },
            },
            b: [
                {
                    a: null,
                },
                {
                    a: {},
                },
            ],
        };
```

Is there any way to dynamically create the `ExpectedType` interface given the `ResponseInterface` Interface and the `filters`? If needed the format of the `filters` array can be changed, as long as the nesting structure remains intact

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, the definition of your `ResponseInterface.b` makes little sense compared to your `ExpectedType.b`, since the former is a Tuple with fixed length 2, while the latter is an array of arbitrary length (update: OP had fixed this). So to make sense, allow me to assume that you mean the following:

```
interface ResponseInterface {
    a: {
        a: {
            a: number;
            b: string;
        };
        b: {
            a: string;
            b: boolean;
        };
    };
    b: {
        a: null | object;
        b: string;
    }[];
}
```

Next, if the filter is written in the form of strings, then you'll need TypeScript to parse your string literal types, which is a feature only exists in the upcoming version 4.1. Even with that power, it is a lot more difficult to rearrange the type structure due the the fact that you list the filters one by one instead of structurally.

So I will recommend you to format your filter in a type instead:

```
type filters = { 'a': { 'a': 'a', 'b': 'b' }, 'b': 'a' };
```

The format should be self-explained. Then you can use the following utility:

```
type PickStructure<T, F> = F extends keyof T ? { [k in F]: T[k] } : {
    [k in keyof F]: k extends keyof T ? (
        T[k] extends (infer U)[] ? PickStructure<U, F[k]>[] : PickStructure<T[k], F[k]>
    ) : never;
};

type ExpectedType = PickStructure<ResponseInterface, filters>;
```

And it works. See this [Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.0.2#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgEoQM4AcD2IMQCS408SyA3gFDK3JwBclNdrjzrnd7IArgLYAjaAG4WXVoKYYwUUAHMxE5AF8lEqR2Xdpsheu3JNgnDgA2EOCAOc141Tc3VlPXmbPIAPshyCAVhAIYDaSunIgivYqANoAumIqVFQIeDLI8ADWEABibmbo2KkQTAW4+EQksIgoALxatOzOEo32LkwAjABMAMwANK0aTADkcHCCQ-3KKpOD9drsI4JwEwNcmrK8EDNc01HbRkzRq3NtyHzu+8qaI1BQcACeRuOXdLvKTYaNb4YHyDd3j0Ez2O31osX6dioYHuWBQMGAZkgUAwyDqFD+yyY6JGQ2Gy16f3Gw3GqgJQyJGKGDihMJQAAVgAgMgBlDZBXhQCAAHgAKgTsgA+VHIbLICAAD0gIAAJiisvccDBkDzkAB+SjIaIZZCgEWxJg8rWxVTILH2LU6kDIeWKvVMbUSqWy60QBVKlXqgAUx0NGWNjogMpRntAMGgyAAqgBKOJq5AMpmsqC8dmcrkR-lGgWxpgJllssAc7m+8EirP2KOms4QABuoiodmhsOQAFFxbCghBpTzacK80mU4W06UisQkWQtukEUiMAKxFQAPQL5AAeQA0slUmB0nAstlp9AuyPykw2x3IN3e2j7C1Th95h0ei9aKDOE5jqFkBstiD9q-NEc7wfjoZx5M+pLHPed6vqwr7gg2YhAA)

Comment: yeah, true, i copy pasta failed on the `ResponseInterface.b`.
works like a charm, thank you very much